shower drain sinking on one side
I've noticed for a while that my shower drain is sinking from one side (attached). I have called a plumber to check and they have confirmed via thermal cameras that no water is leaking through the waterproofing into the sub floor. Based on that the have advised me not to do anything.
I want to sell my place but am concerned that the look will put some buyers off / a building report will classify this as a major structural defect.
Is there an easy way to make this look better? is this a major defect?

The drain should be in a thick mud bed.  Is the subfloor wood?  For a drain to sink like that there must be serious issues underneath.  Can you get under the shower to see what is happening?  I cannot believe a plumber or any tradesman, has said to do nothing.

The bathroom is upstairs so I assume it’s  in wooden subfloors it’s been like this for years. If there was something serious would there not be water discolouration and leaks underneth? Any idea on what the solution is? Will engage a plumber but would like to know how much they will rip me off.

Wait!   your post says , "I've noticed for a while that my shower drain is sinking...". NOW you say "...it's been like this for years."   Which is it...can't be both.  This could just be a very poor amateur shower job.....If it has been like that for years...or it it sinking???

0
Well I’ve noticed for a while but I suspect it’s been there a lot longer. I couldn’t pin point exactly the day when it occurred or when I noticed. Buts not a recent thing. I got a building report done when I moved in (6 yrs ago) which didn’t identify it. So I highly doubt it was there from the start.
In any instance I have a plumber coming to take a look next week. Was just looking for some info on whether is likely to be an east fix or something that will set me back thousands?
